# My imac reports full wifi signal when internet is actually not connected

Tags: wifi, imac, airport

You closed a thread because it was not a real question.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66082/my-wifi-says-i-have-full-connection-but-my-internet-wont-work
I know it sounds weird but the problem described is a problem I am trying to fix.  The funny thing is that my PC, Mac pro, mac book pro, iphone, and sony laptop all connect to the internet fine and my imac spontaneously cannot.
The status bar reports full wi-fi signal.
Internet web browing does not work, mail can not connect, and I have even reset the router.

If you know of anything that might help I would love to hear you share.

-Andrew

Comment: As you were asked in the closed question, can you provided details about your router setup, your computer's IP, a working computer's IP, etc?

Comment: could you post a ping to your router, and to 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS) and traceroutes to both as well.  Also if you could do a ping 127.0.0.1, that would be great.

Comment: Also if you could do a ping www.google.com and a traceroute  www.google.com that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

The wifi signal indicator only reports on the strength of the signal from the base station.  It does not indicate if you have internet connectivity.

If all of your other devices are connecting through the same base station and router, I suggest you click on the wifi indicator, and select open network preferences.  From there it will indicate the status of the connection, e.g. Wi-Fi is connected to "base-station name" and has the IP address x.x.x.x.

If the connection on your iMac to the internet is sporadic, it may be because your router is assigning conflicting IP addresses.

Click on "Advanced", and then TCP/IP.  Compare the settings there with the settings on your MacBook Pro and see if they are set the same way, i.e. Using DHCP.

Beyond that, the question requires quite a bit more troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, it could certainly be an IP conflict, or you may have changed your DNS settings or assinged a staic IP or put in static DNS settings.  Or installed some software that changed your IP stack, like a vpn client... etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Apple's Network Diagnostics tool and see if that suggests anything.  Assuming you are using 10.8, go to System Preferences, select Network, press the "Assist me" button at the bottom of the window, then press Diagnostics.  Follow the steps through and edit your answer with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,  I used to get the same behaviour on my Macbook pro. When I pinged anything on the net the error I got was:

```
ping: sendto: Cannot allocate memory
```

If this is your situation this post will help you:
http://firewallfast.blogspot.com/2012/11/mac-book-networking-stops-working.html
Basically it walks you through turning the TCP/IP stack on and off again on your mac.

Otherwise like everybody says we need more information:
What version of osx are you running, when was the last time you ran a software update.

Once you provide some basic ping stats, we can go on with getting selected output from syslog.